# Is there a performance difference if you pass the query values from function parameters in Java function for Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to add indexes to optimize following query. We are passing the values for orgId and service from the function parameter. What I want to know is does this affect performance in any way? Or is it the same as if we pass the values directly in query.

here template is a jdbc which executes the query

```
        fun queryUsers(orgId: OrgId, service: Service): Set<UserId> {
        val sql = """
                SELECT DISTINCT user_id
                FROM users
                WHERE org_id = :orgId AND service = :service
                """.trimIndent()
        val userIds = mutableSetOf<UserId>()
        template.query(
                "queryUsers",
                sql,
                mapOf("orgId" to orgId.uuid(), "service" to service.toString()),
                {
                    userIds.add(UserId.fromString(it.getString("user_id")))
                })
        return userIds
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not directly , there would be no difference on performance on running this query directly or through a proc.

however It **might** affect the server performance ( It might really not be an issue ) but here is what happens , whenever you run this query directly for each combination of orgId and service , sql engine create a new query plan and cache it to use it.

if you ran the same exact query and if you run this query a lot during short amount of time with different combination values of service and orgid , the cache get filled with query plans for this query and empty out other query plans from cache and make other queries slow.

however since its a very simple query and if you don't run it alot in short amount of time its not a problem at all

but also It is recommended to use stored procedure to avoid sql injection and code re usability and better code maintenance

Comment: in that case, is there a way to prevent that execution plan from being created every time. to specify to use the same plan everytime

Comment: yes , make a stored procedure and execute stored procedure with input params for service and orgid , that way only one execution plan will be created for that stored procedure , regardless of values passed for it's parameters